# GitHub API returns 401 while trying to generate access token

Tags: node.js, github-api, github-app

I'm trying to generate an access token for my GitHub App via GitHub API.

I'm getting a 401 unauthorized response error:

`expiration time' claim ('exp') is too far in the future`

My code:

```
const now = Date.now()
const expiration = now + 60 * 10 // JWT expiration time (10 minute maximum)

const payload = {
  iat: now
  exp: expiration,
  iss: appId
}

const jwt = jwtGenerator(payload, privatePem, { algorithm: "RS256" })
```

Github documentation - https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/

Comment: which package you use for `jwtGenerator` in nodeJS?

Comment: `"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"`.

`jwtGenerator` its just a function which wrap the `sign` function of `jsonwebtoken`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.

The times on different machine were not in sync.
To solve that I set the iat time 30 secs in the past (I tried different time span but it turned out that 30 sec works the best).

```
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 30
const expiration = now + 60 * 10 // JWT expiration time (10 minute maximum)

const payload = {
  iat: now,
  exp: expiration,
  iss: appId
}

const jwt = jwtGenerator(payload, privatePem, { algorithm: "RS256" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Github might be expecting an epoch time in seconds under `exp`.
If you look at the ruby example they use `Time.now.to_i` which returns an epoch time in seconds.
Javascript's `Date.now()` returns an epoch time in milliseconds which is too large, you should try dividing `Date.now()` by 1000, for example:

```js
const now = (Date.now() / 1000)
const expiration = now  + (60 * 10) // JWT expiration time (10 minute maximum)

const payload = {
  iat: now
  exp: expiration,
  iss: appId
}

const jwt = jwtGenerator(payload, privatePem, { algorithm: "RS256" })
```

---

The documentation for `jsonwebtoken` specifically mentions:

[**IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition [POSIX.1] definition "Seconds Since the Epoch"**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim)

Using divide by `1000` and `Math.floor` for proper integer conversion - I was able to get GithubAPI to work with the `jwt.sign`.

Comment: good idea, I tried this also, but it seems like this is not the problem, they are working with both formats